# problem setting up primary keys in mysql database... help?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, primary-key

I have a table set up on a mysql database called "access" with three columns called:

> rights_id, (PRIMARY KEY)
>
> username,
>
> name,

In the rights_id column the user can only input 3 different values ("1","2", or "3") 1 means resource, 2 means manager, and 3 means administrator. my problem occurs when there are more than one row with the same rights_id (ie: more than one administrator).It displays an error that tells me i can't have a duplicate entry for the PRIMARY KEY... i was wondering if there was a way to supress this error and allow me to do this? im using vb.net to interact with my MYSQL database running on a Windows 7 OS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "name" means in that table. If it's safe for me to ignore it . . .

If each username can have only one "rights_id", then the primary key should be username. If each username can have more than one "rights_id"--if user Catcall can have rights_id 1 and 2 at the same time--then your primary key should be the pair of columns (rights_id, username).

Since MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints, you should have a separate table of rights id numbers, containing three rows.

```
create table rights_ids (
  rights_id integer primary key
);
insert into rights_ids values (1);
insert into rights_ids values (2);
insert into rights_ids values (3);
```

Then you can set a foreign key constraint that will prevent any numbers besides those three from appearing in the table named "access".  Something like

```
alter table access
add constraint foreign key (rights_id) references rights_ids (rights_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

`rights_id` is primary key. You can have only distinct values of primary keys in a table. So consider another primary key or do not use `rights_id` column this way. You should learn more about relational databases if you would like to use them.

In my opinion the best solution there is to add anothe column `id` which could be a primary key (you could also set multi-column primary key but this wouldn't fit your data in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Create a compound `PRIMARY KEY` of `rights_id` and `username` (if usernames are unique that is).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't suppress that error. The issue is that `rights_id` is NOT your primary key.

The primary key must be able to uniquely identify a row in your table. If you can have more than 1 `rights_id` entry, then that is NOT able to fulfill the role of a primary key.

Read [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) about unique keys (a primary key is a specific type of unique key).

As Shef pointed out, you'll likely want to use a compound primary key of `rights_id` and `username` if that combination actually uniquely identifies a single row in the table.